# erd diagram Car buying and selling website

Tags: diagram, erd, use-case

In college, I was required to do an ERD for a site that buys, sells, and rents cars. The user is supposed to be able to offer his car for sale or rent, and he can also buy or rent a car.

[erd diagram Car buying and selling website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uePJN.png)

I tried to do what is in the picture, but I think it is a mistake
Does anyone know how I can do this or what I need to modify in the image?

I do not know what to do